# Display SVG in dropdown <select>

Tags: php, html, css, svg

Those flags are in SVG format. The problem is that they don't show up!
If I put them anywhere else everything is working perfectly fine...
I am trying to make a dropdown menu for selecting language.
Thank you!

```html
<select name="language">
    <option value="bg"><span class="flag flag-bel flag-10x"></span>Belgium</option>
    <option value="fr"><span class="flag flag-fra flag-10x"></span>France</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: `select` and `option` markup does not support nested html tags like `span`.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that `<option/>` elements only accept text as content but I can't find a reference to this. You might need to use a custom solution for this.

Comment: Oh... and do you have a solution for that?